# Any way to fix it , WP bakery Uncaught TypeError

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpbakery

[image]
 I have tried to change plugins and apparently

Comment: Full error message                                                                                          
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (checkout.min.js:1)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: Please post error in question instead of screenshots.

Comment: Is there any multilanguage plugin is activated?